# JPA repository join returns all records

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The issues Im facing is that right now, jpa query returns all records, not only from given range. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I really don't know what. Is the jpa join written properly? Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Paper implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "paper_id")
private Long paperId;

private String paperName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "paper", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Stock> stocks;
...
```

and

```
@Entity(name="STOCK")
public class Stock implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="stock_id")
private Long id;
@Column
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime date;
@Column(name="opening_Price", columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2) default '0.00'")
private Double openingPrice;
@Column(name="top_price", columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2) default '0.00'")
private Double topPrice;
@Column(name="lowest_price", columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2) default '0.00'")
private Double lowestPrice;
@Column(name="closing_price", columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2) default '0.00'")
private Double closingPrice;
private Long volume;
@Lob @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(length=100000)
private byte [] graph;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "paper_id")
private Paper paper;
```

so pretty much one to many relation. I have jpa repository with this:

```
@Query("select p from Paper p inner join p.stocks s where (s.date between :preDateTime and :postDateTime) and p.paperName=:paperName")
Paper findByPaperNameAndStockDate(@Param("paperName") String paperName, @Param("preDateTime") DateTime preDateTime, @Param("postDateTime") DateTime postDateTime);
```

I'm calling this method like this:

```
    DateTime date = resolveDate(dateTime);
    DateTime preDate=date.minusDays(1);
    DateTime postDate=date.plusDays(1);
    return paperConverter.convertToDto(paperRepository.findByPaperNameAndStockDate(paperName,preDate,postDate));
```

the resolveDate(String date):

```
private DateTime resolveDate(String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(date+" "+"00:00:00");
    return dateTime;
}
```

I would like to have query which equals to mysql:

```
select *  from Paper inner join STOCK on STOCK.paper_id=Paper.paper_id where Paper.paperName='xyz' and STOCK.date between '2014-12-28 00:00:00' and '2014-12-30 00:00:00' ;
```

I can see two queries after running this method:

```
Hibernate: select paper0_.paper_id as paper1_0_, paper0_.paperName as paperName0_ from Paper paper0_ inner join STOCK stocks1_ on paper0_.paper_id=stocks1_.paper_id where (stocks1_.date between ? and ?) and paper0_.paperName=? limit ?
```

and the second one:

```
Hibernate: select stocks0_.paper_id as paper9_0_1_, stocks0_.stock_id as stock1_1_, stocks0_.stock_id as stock1_2_0_, stocks0_.closing_price as closing2_2_0_, stocks0_.date as date2_0_, stocks0_.graph as graph2_0_, stocks0_.lowest_price as lowest5_2_0_, stocks0_.opening_Price as opening6_2_0_, stocks0_.paper_id as paper9_2_0_, stocks0_.top_price as top7_2_0_, stocks0_.volume as volume2_0_ from STOCK stocks0_ where stocks0_.paper_id=?
```

The log lines:

```
12:17:43,320 DEBUG SQL:104 - select paper0_.paper_id as paper1_0_, paper0_.paperName as paperName0_ from Paper paper0_ inner join STOCK stocks1_ on paper0_.paper_id=stocks1_.paper_id where (stocks1_.date between ? and ?) and paper0_.paperName=? limit ?
Hibernate: select paper0_.paper_id as paper1_0_, paper0_.paperName as paperName0_ from Paper paper0_ inner join STOCK stocks1_ on paper0_.paper_id=stocks1_.paper_id where (stocks1_.date between ? and ?) and paper0_.paperName=? limit ?
12:17:43,405 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - 2014-12-27 23:00:00.0
12:17:43,437 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - 2014-12-29 23:00:00.0
12:17:43,441 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - xyz
```

Comment: Could you please turn on the SQL in the hibernate properties and see what  sql is sent to db?

Comment: I've updated the post with the queries. Apologies for forgeting to do it before

Comment: Weird. It would be interesting to see the full logging, if you set loglevel = trace you will see parameter values and each query invocation.

Comment: I've attached the log lines, the strange thing are those dates, if the date to be listed is 2014-12-29, I was expecting something like 2014-12-30 and 2014-12-28